# Operadores en una cadena de caracteres ¿cómo sumar cadenas cuando por ejemplo el operador de suma (+) esta dentro de una cadena de caracteres?

Tags: c++

Necesito saber como funcionan los operadoresde suma, resta, multiplicacion y division en una cadena de tipo char o como hacer que hagan la suma de 2 cadenas en el caso de la suma.

se que primero debo transformar la cadena de caracteres a una cadena de enteros para poder sumar cadenas de enteros, aquí les muestro un ejemplo:

al tener esta cadena:

```
char cadena[] = {'1','2','+','2','0'};
```

con la función `atoi` se que puedo transformar la cadena de tipo cararter a tipo entero asi:

```
char cadena[] = {'1','2','+','2','0'};

int numero; //variable donde se almacenara el valor entero

 numero = atoi(cadena); //transformando la cadena de caracteres a enteros.
```

con esto estaría transformado la cadena de tipo char a una tipo entero.

Pero es aquí donde me resulta la duda: como hacer para quer me sume las 2 cadenas enteras del ejemplo anterior...

`char cadena[] = {'1','2','+','2','0'}` y que me arroje el resultado de 32 en este ejemplo.

Answer (score 3):

> se que primero debo transformar la cadena de caracteres a una cadena de enteros para poder sumar cadenas de enteros

Aquí te equivocas. Lo que tienes que hacer es extraer de la cadena de caracteres **los dos enteros** que conforman la operación. Es decir, tienes que pasar de esto:

```
char cadena[] = {'1','2','+','2','0'};
```

a esto:

```
int a = 12;
int b = 20;
int numero = a + b;
```

¿Cómo conseguimos llegar hasta aquí? Bueno, para ello tienes que ver dónde empieza y termina cada número:

- El inicio del primer número es el inicio de la cadena, el final lo marca un caracter no numérico.
- El segundo número empieza tras el caracter no numérico y termina al final de la cadena.

En tu caso estás usando la función `atoi`. Si seguimos usando esta función el código podría quedar así:

```
char cadena[] = "12+20";
int a = atoi(cadena);

// localizamos el separador (asumimos que es una suma
char* it;
for( it = cadena; std::isdigit(*it); ++it );

// avanzamos al inicio del segundo digito
++it;

int b = atoi(it);

int numero = a + b;
```

Aunque esto es más una solución al estilo C. En C++ podríamos usar objetos para simplificarnos un poco la vida:

```
char cadena[] = "12+20";
std::stringstream ss;
ss << cadena;

int a, b;

ss >> a >> b;
int numero = a + b;
```

Queda en tu mano detectar el tipo de operación a realizar y actuar en consecuencia.

Answer (score 1):

> Necesito saber como funcionan los operadoresde suma, resta, multiplicacion y division en una cadena de tipo char o como hacer que hagan la suma de 2 cadenas en el caso de la suma.

No funcionan, son sólo texto. Es como si preguntaras cómo hacer mosto con las uvas del [Bodegón con cuatro racimos de uvas de Juan Fernández el Labrador](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=bodeg%c3%b3n+con+cuatro+racimos+de+uvas+de+juan+fern%c3%a1ndez+el+labrador): No podrás, es un óleo sobre lienzo, no son uvas de verdad.

---

Hay muchísimas opciones para transformar un texto en una operación matemática arbitraria, [eferion te ofrece una solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/261052/2742) basada en leer los operandos por separado y asumir el operador, yo propongo procesar los datos secuencialmente y operar según el operador recibido:

```
std::string op1, op2;
char op{};

for (auto c : operacion)
{
    if (std::isdigit(c))
        (op ? op2 : op1).push_back(c);
    else
        op = c;
}
```

El código anterior guarda en `op1` el primer operando, en `op2` el segundo y en `op` el operador, puedes transformar en número cada uno de los operandos así:

```
int n1, n2;
std::from_chars(op1.data(), op1.data() + op1.length(), n1);
std::from_chars(op2.data(), op2.data() + op2.length(), n2);
```

Y puedes seleccionar la operación así:

```
switch (op)
{
    case '+':
        std::cout << n1 + n2;
        break;
    // Mas operadores
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3pd8Ir8A0QJt3OTE).